# Show fragment as a dialog or as a usual activity

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, fragment

In my app I've got a fragment which is called "About". On handhelds I want this fragment to look like a usual activity but on tablets I want it to be a dialog. Which way is preferred to handle this situation?

Comment: I'd say my alternative suggestion comes from a pretty credible source. It's straight from Google.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Make a style for this in your `styles.xml` (two styles.xml files, one in the `values` folder, the other in a `values-large` folder) but have the style you put in the values-large folder inherit from Theme.Dialog. Then have your fragment use that style. The system will take care of the rest.

Alternatively, make your class a DialogFragment, and then either embed it into a view hierarchy, or show it as a dialog, as explained here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#DialogOrEmbed

Comment: Alternative is for API 11+. Thats the only problem.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use Android support? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html