# Android fragment show as dialogfragment or usual fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

What I am trying to achieve is to have a fragment that on tablet it shows as a `DialogFragment`, while on smartphone it would be shown as a regular fragment. I am aware there is already a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593415/show-fragment-as-a-dialog-or-as-a-usual-activity), but I am not able to make that work - apply the style to fragment.

To show things top down, MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_next) {
            decideToNext();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void decideToNext() {
        String device = getString(R.string.device);
        if ("normal".equalsIgnoreCase(device)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailedActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if ("large".equalsIgnoreCase(device)) {
            Log.d("SOME_TAG", "Yes, I am seeing this line on tablet only");
            DetailedFragment fragment = DetailedFragment.newInstance();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(fragment, "MAGIC_TAG").commit();
        }
    }

}
```

DetailedActivity is nothing much:

```
public class DetailedActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detailed_activity);
    }
}
```

its layout:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_container"
    android:name="com.myapps.sampleandroid.DetailedFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and the interesting `DetailedFragment`:

```
public class DetailedFragment extends Fragment {

    public static DetailedFragment newInstance() {
        return new DetailedFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Context contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.MyDialogTheme);
        LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);
        return localInflater.inflate(R.layout.detailed_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

... and its layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Regular Text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button Dummy" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In `onCreateView` I've tried to set the custom styling but it doesn't seem to work for tablet.

**Styling**

res/values/styles.xml contains:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    </style>

    <style name="MyDialogTheme" />

</resources>
```

while res/values-large/styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Is there anything I should add here? -->
    <style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"/>
</resources>
```

I've nested `MyDialogTheme` from `Theme.Dialog`, but it doesn't seem to help.

On smartphone when tapping on "NEXT" action bar menu item I am seeing the detailed activity (snapshot from an SG2):
[image: snapshot from an SG2]

while tapping on the same "NEXT" menu item from the tablet it doesn't do anything (except viewing the message on Logcat: `Yes, I am seeing this line`).
[image]

What should I add more in styles.xml or in code in order to see `DetailedFragment` as a dialog for tablet?

**EDIT**

I've tried the solution *Little Child* proposed (to have a `DialogFragment` contain my initial fragment and show it). So, I've added a `WrapperDetailedFragment`:

```
public class WraperDetailedFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.wrap_detailed_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

its layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_container_dialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/wrapped_fragment_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.myapps.sampleandroid.DetailedFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The code from MainActivity changes to:

```
private void decideToNext() {
    String device = getString(R.string.device);
    if ("normal".equalsIgnoreCase(device)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailedActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if ("large".equalsIgnoreCase(device)) {
        Log.d("SOME_TAG", "Yes, I am seeing this line ...");
        WraperDetailedFragment fragment = new WraperDetailedFragment();
        fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "MAGICAL_TAG");
    }
}
```

but when I'm trying to add this DialogFragment I am getting the following crash:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at com.myapps.sampleandroid.WraperDetailedFragment.onCreateView(WraperDetailedFragment.java:12)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:304)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at com.myapps.sampleandroid.WraperDetailedFragment.onCreateView(WraperDetailedFragment.java:12)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #8: Duplicate id 0x7f050047, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.myapps.sampleandroid.DetailedFragment
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:290)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
    ... 28 more
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This issue can be easily fixed if instead of trying to make a `Fragment` look like a `DialogFragment` I would look from the opposite angle: make a `DialogFragment` look like a `Fragment` - after all, a `DialogFragment` is a `Fragment`!

The key of this fix is to call or not [`DialogFragment.setShowsDialog();`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#setShowsDialog%28boolean%29)

So changing the `DetailedFragment` to:

```
public class DetailedFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String ARG_SHOW_AS_DIALOG = "DetailedFragment.ARG_SHOW_AS_DIALOG";

    public static DetailedFragment newInstance(boolean showAsDialog) {
        DetailedFragment fragment = new DetailedFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putBoolean(ARG_SHOW_AS_DIALOG, showAsDialog);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public static DetailedFragment newInstance() {
        return newInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
            setShowsDialog(args.getBoolean(ARG_SHOW_AS_DIALOG, true));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.detailed_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

its layout remains as it was, `DetailedActivity` changes to:

```
public class DetailedActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detailed_activity);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            DetailedFragment fragment = DetailedFragment.newInstance(false);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.root_layout_details, fragment, "Some_tag").commit();
        }
    }
}
```

its layout as well:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout_details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and the caller activity does only:

```
private void decideToNext() {
    String device = getString(R.string.device);
    if ("normal".equalsIgnoreCase(device)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailedActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if ("large".equalsIgnoreCase(device)) {
        DetailedFragment fragment = DetailedFragment.newInstance();
        fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Tablet_specific");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make a `DialogFragment` show as a regular `Fragment`, call `add()` or `replace()` using a resource ID for the fragment container, e.g

```
beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
```

But to make the DialogFragment display as a dialog, call `add(fragment, "Fragment Tag")`. Behind the scenes this results in a call to `add(resId, fragment)`, setting the resource ID for the fragment container to 0, which causes the `DialogFragment` to set its `showAsDialog` option to true.

As a consequence you can use a dialog fragment as a dialog or a regular fragment - depending on your needs - without needing to create any special logic to do it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have been there and done that. To make a `DialogFragment` you need a layout defined  in XML. Say, for this you have `LinearLayout` as root. In this `LinearLayout` you can add a `fragment class="...."` and when you display your `DialogFragment`, it will be the same `Fragment` you displayed side by side on the tablet now displayed in a `DialogFragment`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
<fragment class="com.example.tqafragments.FeedFragment" android:id="@+id/feedFragment" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Like so. And inflate this in your `DialogFragment`

Comment: I don't think you understood the question: I need a fragment to be displayed as `DialogFragment` for tablet, but the same fragment must remain a non-DialogFragment for smartphone. The answer you have provided shows how to display a fragment - bytheway, I think you'll get an `IllegalArgumentException` if `FeedFragment` is a `DialogFragment`: `DialogFragment` can not be attached to a container view`. A DialogFragment can only be added through FragmentTransation add/replace method after the root is created.

Comment: Not at all. You will have to define different layout for small phones and for tablets. I hope you are aware you can do that :) For tablets, the fragments will be displayed side-by-side.
What you missed is.. the `DialogFragment` **will contain** the `Fragment`.

Comment: So if I understand you correct: you're suggesting to have a DialogFragment and inside of it the Fragment I am interested to show?

Comment: Will give it a shot tomorrow. Anyway, your idea is interesting. +1

Comment: Absolutely. A `Fragment` inside a `DialogFragment`

Comment: I've tried your solution and I am getting a crash, some `IllegalArgumentException`. Can you have a look?

Comment: It says duplicate ID. `Binary XML file line #8: Duplicate id 0x7f050047, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.myapps.sampleandroid.DetailedFragment`

Comment: tag is null as you cannot specify from xml, and there is no duplicate id. Parent has an ID. I'll have to dig in Android code to see what this error is about, but at a first glance this doesn't work - at least I wasn't able to make it work. You have all the resources above (class names and layouts). If you modify above to make it work I'll accept your answer even though my answer seems cleaner. I like to have alternatives ...

Comment: Accepting my answer since you didn't reply yet.