# Android - show fragment within a dialog

Tags: android, fragment, fragmentmanager

I'm developing an android app that uses fragments as the base of the navigation flow.
In some point, i fell in a problem that I couldnt resolve.

All fragments extends from a base class which has some properties that the navigation manager needs, called NavigationFragment, which extends from Fragment.

Now, I need to show one of this fragments like a popup, on a Dialog.

I found the amazing class DialogFragment that does the trick, but the problem is that the fragment cannot extend from this because it already extends from NavigationFragment.

I dont want to make NavigationFragment a DialogFragment, because there are only a few of them that will be shown as a popup.

Do you know an alternative to this? like a Dialog that can contain a Fragment, or something else?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you can extend from the DialogFragment and implement a navigation controller. This would be the best option if you are overriding your navigation commands in each subclass, anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not overriding the commands in the subclasses. The NavigationFragment overrides the onViewCreated from the fragment, and has an instance of a listener to communicate with the navigation controller. I'm considering the option of make a NavigationDialogFragment, that extends DialogFragment and implements these functions. It's not what I wanted because I need to modify the navigation controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have come across is not really an issue at all.
You should make `NavigationFragment` extend `DialogFragment`, and then only call [`setShowsDialog(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#setShowsDialog%28boolean%29) in `onCreate` for those you want to show as a Dialog. From the [helpDoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#setShowsDialog%28boolean%29),

setShowsDialog

> Controls whether this fragment should be shown in a dialog. If not set, no Dialog will be created in onActivityCreated(Bundle), and the
>   fragment's view hierarchy will thus not be added to it. This allows
>   you to instead use it as a normal fragment (embedded inside of its
>   activity).
>
> This is normally set for you based on whether the fragment is associated with a container view ID passed to
>   FragmentTransaction.add(int, Fragment). If the fragment was added with
>   a container, setShowsDialog will be initialized to false; otherwise,
>   it will be true.

See [Android fragment show as dialogfragment or usual fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578295/android-fragment-show-as-dialogfragment-or-usual-fragment/18613284#18613284), or better yet, the official documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#DialogOrEmbed) for a more detailed explanation on how to utilize this function.