# Reusing my views in Activity and a Dialog

Tags: android

[image]UI/UX of my current application has a MainActivity and a couple of other activities now i have a dialog opening across all activities and the layout of that dialog is almost same as MainActivity , How can i reuse my layout and initialization code and other click events so that both Activity and Dialog use the same events

1. The way in which i thought is to create a fragment and put all code in there and basically populate the same fragment in both of these cases

Is there any other way in which i can achieve abstraction ?

edit : Please refer the picture this dialog that you see this dialog also is shown on base screen below which is an activity and is a persistent dialog across all screens

Comment: question is not clear can you please provide snapshots?

Comment: please check the image and why the hell has it been downvoted

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question by looking at other posts so if anyone is looking out for this solution refer
[Android fragment show as dialogfragment or usual fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578295/android-fragment-show-as-dialogfragment-or-usual-fragment)

Comment: so now the same fragment can be used as a dialog and normal fragment which brings the abstraction so that i don't have to redefine views and clicks and refer to same functionality