# Should I create a fragment for my app?

Tags: java, android, layout

I'm a bit confused as to wether I should create a plain `activity` or a `fragmentactivity`. My app is displaying an `expandableListView` and a `dialog`. Thats it (pretty much).

I cannot find any instance that my app would be better if I used a `fragmentActivtiy` because first of all my app is not designed for tablets, and second I'm not adding or doing anything to my `main activity` during runtime to change the views.

My problem is that it seems it is a must to use fragments, because when I checked out Android dev site on `dialogs`, it only explains how to implement them using fragments. Are plain activities highly un-recommended or I just have to judge my app, and are all features such as dialogs available for plain activities? (And can someone please give me a link to a good source where I can learn about dialogs in a normal activity?)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

It says here that you should use a fragment but does that mean i have to go all out and make my main activity a fragment?

Comment: As long as your Dialog is concerned you can use AlertDialog and inflate an xml of your own choice and set that xml as view using `alertDialog.setView(view)` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some discussion about using Fragment or Activity for dialog: [Show fragment as a dialog or as a usual activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593415/show-fragment-as-a-dialog-or-as-a-usual-activity)

If you want to make your dialog as Activity, hope this tutorial helps:
[How to create Dialog activity in Android?](http://www.javabeat.net/dialog-activity-android/)

Answer (score 0):

A `FragmentActivity` *is* an `Activity` because it extends `Activity` See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html). The question the mean to ask is really a question for your self, do you want your app to support API >= 11 (3.0 Honeycomb) or API >= 4?

In API 11 Android introduced the concept of Fragments to deal with creating apps particularly tablets. But to add support for all the devices still running < 11 they created the Support v4 library which is where `FragmentActivity` lives.

If you are not using Fragments at all then just use `Activity` because it's available at all API levels. (it just got added functionality in >=11). If you want to support  >=4 and may use Fragments then use `FragmentActivity` and your covered. I noticed things in the v4 library have started to be deprecated (starting to be phased out by Google). Personally, I won't make a *new* app with API <14 and suggest you stay above 11.

As far as `Dialogs` go. You don't need to used a `DialogFragment` but same question above applies to API level. I typically just used [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) to show mine even if I'm using Fragments.

Hopefully this clears some things up for you. Happy Codin'